# Autowire EntityManagerFactory annotations is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm injecting @PersistenceContext into my DAO classes like

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

@PersistenceContext is configured in my project via spring xml configuration.  I'm trying to convert the following spring xml configuration to annotations

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="com.company.myagentmonitor.model"
        p:dataSource-ref="companyDataSource"
        >
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transactions -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I'm trying to convert this config to @Beans I can autowire in my DAO classes.  What I have currently is not working

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(companyDataSource());
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.company.myagentmonitor.model" });
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}
```

I basically get a null pointer exception at runtime.  I think it has something to do with the way I'm creating or using EntityManagerFactory.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.initProxyClassLoa
der(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:199) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.<init>(SharedEnti
tyManagerCreator.java:191) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.j
ava:163) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityMa
nager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToIn
ject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:
169) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-bea
ns-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(Persiste
nceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Can someone take a look?  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't see `companyDataSource()` method in the configuration.

Comment: It is there I will post it when I get back.  I know the data source bean is working because I'm using it in another part of the project.

Comment: try with this ` @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(companyDataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.company.myagentmonitor.model" });
      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      return em;
   }`

Comment: I tried substituting your bean definition and I get this error now: AppConfig.java:104: error: incompatible types: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cannot be converted to EntityManagerFactory
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());

Comment: suppose you refer this post [link](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa)

Comment: Instead of doing `getObject` in your `EntityManagerFactory` method just return the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Spring will do the `getObject` and register the appropriate callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
}
```

to this

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
     return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

and in your transactionManager you also change

```
transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
```

to

```
jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all you shouldn't be calling `getObject` in your `entityManagerMethod()` let Spring handle that for you. Just return the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(companyDataSource());
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.company.myagentmonitor.model" });
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

The `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` implements several interfaces which spring detects and as such will register callbacks for (init and destruction) and also inject some needed dependencies.

Next where you need the `EntityManagerFactory` just inject it into your method instead of calling `entityManagerFactory()`.

```
@Bean
JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}
```